# Add grand total to totals in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the bellow query and it works.
I just need to add a line at the bottom that gives the grand total

```
SELECT ItemType.Description,
        SUM(Price * Quantity)as 'TOTAL'
FROM [MIETRAK].[dbo].[PurchaseOrderReceivingLine]
join Item 
  on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.ItemFK = item.ItemPK
join ItemType 
  on Item.ItemTypeFK = ItemType.ItemTypePK
join PurchaseOrderReceiving 
  on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.PurchaseOrderReceivingFK = PurchaseOrderReceiving.PurchaseOrderReceivingPK
where InvoiceDate >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)  
  and InvoiceDate < dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
group by ItemType.Description
```

Comment: Why don't you just calculate the grand total in whatever reporting tool/code that you're using to present the data?

Comment: you could put the results of your query in a temporary table and then put a grand total from your temp table. Then you just union them together with your grand total at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CTE` and `UNION` the rows with grand total row.

```
with CTE
(
   SELECT ItemType.Description,
        SUM(Price * Quantity)as 'TOTAL'
        FROM [MIETRAK].[dbo].[PurchaseOrderReceivingLine]
  join Item on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.ItemFK = item.ItemPK
  join ItemType on Item.ItemTypeFK = ItemType.ItemTypePK
  join PurchaseOrderReceiving on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.PurchaseOrderReceivingFK = PurchaseOrderReceiving.PurchaseOrderReceivingPK
  where  
  InvoiceDate >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)  
  and InvoiceDate < dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
  group by ItemType.Description
)

SELECT Description,TOTAL FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT 'GRAND TOTAL',SUM(TOTAL) FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

use your returned result as temp result

```
;WITH TEMP AS(
SELECT ItemType.Description, SUM(Price * Quantity)as 'TOTAL'
FROM [MIETRAK].[dbo].[PurchaseOrderReceivingLine]
join Item 
  on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.ItemFK = item.ItemPK
join ItemType 
  on Item.ItemTypeFK = ItemType.ItemTypePK
join PurchaseOrderReceiving 
  on PurchaseOrderReceivingLine.PurchaseOrderReceivingFK = PurchaseOrderReceiving.PurchaseOrderReceivingPK
where InvoiceDate >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)  
  and InvoiceDate < dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
group by ItemType.Description
)
SELECT * FROM TEMP
UNION
SELECT 'BIG SUM',SUM(TOTAL) TEMP
```